# shiny: Order of reactive v reactiveValues

Tags: r, shiny

I am struggling to wrap my head around when to use `reactiveValues` and when I can used `reactive`. For example, I am wanting to create an app where I have a reactive value that is modified by a slider. Take this app:

```r
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("multiplier", "Multiplier", min = 0, max = 10, value = 1, step = 0.1),
  actionButton("update_button", "Add Rows"),
  tableOutput("data_frame")
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Create reactiveValues object to store data
  rv <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(4, 5, 6)))
  
  # Add rows to data frame when button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$update_button, {
    # Code to add rows to data frame goes here
    new_rows <- data.frame(x = c(7, 8, 9), y = c(10, 11, 12))
    rv$data <- rbind(rv$data, new_rows)
  })
  
  # Multiply values in data frame by the value of the slider
  updated_data <- reactive({
    rv$data * input$multiplier
  })
  
  # Display data frame
  output$data_frame <- renderTable({
    updated_data()
  })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This works well but I want to understand `reactiveValues`. For example can anyone explain why if I make the `reactive` object first to do some multiplication I get an error. Can `reactiveValues` *only* take existing data?

```r
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("multiplier", "Multiplier", min = 0, max = 10, value = 1, step = 0.1),
  actionButton("update_button", "Add Rows"),
  tableOutput("data_frame")
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output) {

  my_data <- reactive({
    df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(4, 5, 6))
    df$x <- df$x * input$multiplier
    df
  })
  
  # Create reactiveValues object to store data
  val <- reactiveValues(rv = NULL)
  val$rv = my_data()
  
  # Add rows to data frame when button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$update_button, {
    # Code to add rows to data frame goes here
    new_rows <- data.frame(x = c(7, 8, 9), y = c(10, 11, 12))
    val$rv <- rbind(val$rv, new_rows)
  })
  
  
  # Display data frame
  output$data_frame <- renderTable({
    val()
  })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with `reactiveValues`. When trying to assign the value of your reactive to your reactiveVal you're trying to access the value of a `reactive` outside of a reactive context. Hence you get an error as the value of a reactive or input can only be accessed within another reactive or an observe or a render function.

Comment: e.g. `observe({ val$rv = my_data() })` will work.

Comment: Interesting. It does basically but now I have to figure out where the `new_rows` dissappear when I use the slider.

Comment: (: Was just meant as an example. When adding the `observe` to your code the reactiveValue gets updated each time my_data() changes, i.e. if you move the slider.